# При переходе с одной страницы на другую открыть вкладку (accordion) с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

На главной странице сайта есть ссылки на страницу с услугами. На странице с услугами есть accordion, который содержит скрытые списки услуг, и раскрывается по клику на соответствующий заголовок.

Задача в том, что надо чтобы осуществлялся переход на другую страницу и одновременно открывалась соответствующая вкладка с услугами.

Как сделать такое с помощью js?

Comment: Плавно или нет?

Comment: как выглядит аккордион?

Comment: это бутстрап http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: а как тут можно плавно сделать? хотя это не нужно, главное чтобы работало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделала так:

Передаю в ссылке `id`

```
<a href="services.html#hygiene"></a>
```

В js проверяю:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('.card a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == hash){
        $(this).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно и без использования скрипта. Одним якорем и функцией target:

```css
p {display: none;}

p:target {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="#elem0">Открыть часть 1</a>
<a href="#elem1">Открыть часть 2</a>
<a href="#elem2">Открыть часть 3</a>

<p id="elem0">Часть 1</p>
<p id="elem1">Часть 2</p>
<p id="elem2">Часть 3</p>
```

Comment: без скрипта нельзя, т.к. элементы находятся на разных страницах

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, воспользуйтесь нижеперечисленными методами

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="tab1">Tab</li>
  <li id="tab2">Tab2</li>
  <li id="tab3">Tab3</li>
</ul>
```

Данную проблему вы можете решить с помощью якорей (anchor), т.е вы перенаправляете пользователя по ссылке услуг и в конце URL добавляете якорь, например

```
www.vashsite.ru/uslugi#tab3
```

После этого на странице услуг вы через JS проверяете имеется ли якорь

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.split('#');
```

`if(anchor[1] != ''){$('ul li').slideUp(); $('#'+anchor[1]).slideDown();}`