# jQuery UI, как сделать ссылку на определенную вкладку таба?

Tags: javascript, html5, вёрстка

На странице сайта есть табы сделанные с помощью jQuery UI и нужно на совсем другой странице сделать ссылку, по клику на которой будет происходить переход на страницу с табами и включаться определенная вкладка таба. 
Но как это сделать, ведь в jQuery UI при переключении вкладок табов, URL не меняется?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону location.

Comment: при открытии страницы смотреть якорь и переключать программно

Comment: что-то из этого - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616150/223826

Comment: или этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/745987/223826, хотя тут более экстравагантное решение